# Trying to create items to my MySQL database via my localhost as backend and c# as frontend

Tags: c#, php, mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have a backend code where I echo out the results in my database as an array Jobject and also a code (that iam going to show first) where I try to make something happen when I want to create something on my DB via my frontend.

So my question is, How should I adjust the first part of the code so my frontend code can reach it and so that the info that the user puts in the frontcode gets into the database?

```
<?php 

$mysql_pekare= new mysqli ("host", " user","pass", "db");

$stmt = $mysql_pekare->prepare("INSERT INTO Events(`Name`, `Title`) VALUES(?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $namn, $age);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysql_pekare->close();

?>
```

And finally this is my frontend code (C#) where I try to reach the DB and my PHP-code and create something into my DB from my frontend:

```
static public async Task <bool>  createOurMainInfo (string userId, string thename, string thetitle)
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var postData = new Dictionary <string, string> ();

        postData.Add ("Name", thename);
        postData.Add ("Title", thetitle);

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await httpClientRequest.PostAsync("http://localhost/Events.php", content);
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        return  true;
     }
```

Updated code:

```
$value1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$value2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$mysql_pekare= new mysqli ("", "","", "");

$stmt = $mysql_pekare->prepare("INSERT INTO Events(`Name`, `Title`) VALUES(?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $value1, $value2);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysql_pekare->close();

echo $value1->Name;
echo $value2->Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

The c# code posts 2 parameters as Name and Title as json, so your 1st php code should expect 2 parameters named as Name and Title in json format and submit those 2 parameters to the insert query in the place of $namn and $age.

Since you are posting the data as json, you cannot use $_POST directly. [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) enables you to read raw post input and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) can be used to decode the contents of a json string into objects.

```
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $value->Title; //should return title
```

Obviously, I would add some authentication and authorisation to the php code and some input checking on the json parameters before submitting them to the database.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST Name, $_POST Title); Would I add it directly like this?

Comment: Pls check the link to the manual I gave on $_post, but sg like that is needed. But pls try the code yourself.

Comment: Yeah I meant like this: $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST ['Name'], $_POST ['Title']); . When I try to test it on my frontend it doesnt work and the info i entered wont save on the db

Comment: I'm sorry, but the "does not work" is a meaningless feedback! Debug your code to retrieve a proper error message or understand where things go south. There is still a space before [ in variable names.

Comment: In the log when I create something in my frontend I recieve this: {"Name":"Test1","Title":"Testtt1"} so the info reaches the 2 parameters in the frontcode i assume atleast. I am not sure how else I can check what is wrong.

Comment: I also recieve the current info from the DB. So i recieve the json that alrdy exists on the database in my frontend log.

Comment: By adding debugging code to your php code, perhaps? You can echo php error messages, or save them to a file. You can also catch sql error messages from php and output them as well.

Comment: Okok. I have not used that kind of code before. How could it look?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a Q/A site, not an introduction to php coding class.

Comment: I am aware of that, but ofc I cant accept your answer as the issue still remains

Comment: Updated my answer. However, pls do your own debugging from now on. If you are unable to debug code and can only accept full copy-paste code, then SO may not be the right place for your questions!

Comment: Updated my question with a new code (in the buttom). Am I working towards the right direction?

Comment: Not really. No need to access the raw input twice, only once. Pls make an effort to understand what is in $value. I linked the relevant php manual pages. The echos are for debugging purposes only. Have you checked their return value at all?

Comment: Okok. Yeah trying to solve this in a rush as it is late here. Well gotta keep working on it tomorrow then. I will keep you updated if I make any progress with your tips tomorrow. Thx

Comment: One more hint then: json_decode() returns an object. That object holds all data within the json (name and title).

Comment: $stmt->bind_param(array("ss", $value[0], $value[1])); Something like this?

Comment: I get this error: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Comment: I'm sorry, but why are you guessing? 1. I gave you the sample code how to access the parameters. 2. You are still not debugging your own code.

Comment: Yeah, I am just having trouble to get the object into two pieces so I can add it into my Values. How can I chop up json_decode() into two?

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("ss", $value->Name, $value->Title); Nothing adds into the DB with this code either. I am sorry for not reading to much into this. I am mostly into frontcode, so I just want to get this backend done so I can focus on the front mor ein the future. I just want to make this work so I can work with DB items in my front.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you helped me get this done.

Comment: I get nothing when I type this: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data); and echo $data["Name"]; same with $data->Title;

Comment: when I use "encode" instead, i get 3 of these """

Comment: the problem is that it doesnt find my c# inputted info.